# CSS - What the content css property mean

Tags: html, css

I would like to know what those content css property mean

```
figure > figcaption::before{
   // what this propertie mean
   content: "*\002607\0000a0caption\A*";
   white-space: pre;
   font-style: italic;/*emphasized text*/
   font-variant: small-caps;
   font-size: 0.5em;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: I've marked it.

Answer (score 0):

**[CSS content Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp)**

> The content property is used with the :before and :after pseudo-elements, to insert generated content.

**CSS Syntax**

```
content: normal|none|counter|attr|string|open-quote|close-quote|no-open-quote|no-close-quote|url|initial|inherit;
```

example

---

```css
div {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: blue;
  line-height: 250px;
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

h3:before{
  content: "\00a9";
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
  top: -5px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>This is an example for css property content</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you do not use

> content: "*\002607\0000a0caption\A*";

in your program

> `<figcaption>`

then

> `<figcaption>`

text will not be populated with

> 'curved right arrow with text "CAPTION" '

at the top of the `<figcaption>` text.

Answer (score -3):

I suppose this is symbol code, such as:

```html
    <p>&#8630;</p>
```